VSCode Prettier extension scrolls to bottom of file on save
Whenever I make a change to a file with Prettier enabled and save it, the cursor moves to the last position in the file. If I disable Prettier there are no issues.
Both VSCode and Prettier is up to date, and no other extension is enabled.
It seems like this only happens in a .js file with 3500 lines. Other .js, .cjs and .html files don't have this issue.
